# How to compare a regex object with a list in python?

Tags: python, regex

My code is:

```
import re
x=["Set","Sets","ShowSets","Union","Intersect","SetUnion","SetIntersect"]
print (x)
while True:
    text_to_search = input('Introduce an instruction: ')

    for match1 in re.finditer('Sets?|ShowSet|ShowSets|Union|Intersect|SetUnion|SetIntersect',text_to_search):
        print("Instruction: ")
        #x.append(match1)
        print(match1)
    for match2 in re.finditer(r':=|{|}|;',text_to_search):
        print("Operator: ")
        print(match2)
    for match3 in re.finditer(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+',text_to_search):
        if match3 in x:
            pass
        else:
            print("ID: ")
            print(match3)
    print(x)
```

What I'm trying to do in the third for is to print all the words that are not instruction (avoid printing Set, Sets, ShowSets etc) but the problem is that isnt doing the `if match3 in x:`so the program is printing:
['Set', 'Sets', 'ShowSets', 'Union', 'Intersect', 'SetUnion', 'SetIntersect']

```
Introduce an instrucción: Set Hi
Instruction: 
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='Set'>
ID: 
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='Set'>
ID: 
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 6), match='Hi'>
['Set', 'Sets', 'ShowSets', 'Union', 'Intersect', 'SetUnion', 'SetIntersect']
```

Instead of:

```
Introduce an instrucción: Set Hi
    Instruction: 
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='Set'>
 ID: 
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 6), match='Hi'>
    ['Set', 'Sets', 'ShowSets', 'Union', 'Intersect', 'SetUnion', 'SetIntersect']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the matched text first:

```
if match3.group() in x:
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but is if you dont mind, can you explain me why it worked?

Comment: @SebasSilva how are you planning on using these match objects if not with `group()`?

Comment: I have already read  that group() returns the object as string, 
sorry for the inconvenience